# Find duplicates in variable

Tags: bash, sorting, find, duplicates

I am trying to found duplicates in a list. Right now I am searching for a list of files with specific file extensions and storing these files in a variable called 'files'.

For each file in files I am formatting these so only have the filename.

I then want to check this list for duplicates but I can't get my head around it.

```
files=$(find /root/123 -type f \( -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.bat" \))

for file in $files; do
   formatted=$(echo ${file##*/})
   unique=$(echo $formatted | sort | uniq -c)
done

echo $unique
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

> Find duplicates in variable

I guess you don't need to reinvent the wheel, simply use [fdupes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fdupes) ot [fslint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/)

Depending on your system, you can install it by using:

```
yum -y install fdupes
```

or

```
apt-get install fdupes
```

---

Usage of `fdupes` is pretty straight forward:

```
fdupes /path/to/dir
```

If you just need the `.txt` files, you can pipe the result to  `grep`, i.e.:

```
fdupes /path/to/dir | grep .txt
```

Comment: The OP doesn't seem, at least at the moment, to be looking for files with identical contents. Though perhaps that's just an as-yet uncorrected error.

Comment: **"I am trying to found duplicates in a list"** The _list_  comes from the `find` output, so I guess the OP needs to find dups.

Comment: Yes, but the output of `find` is file names. Those *names* are then being stripped of extensions and then it appears counted for duplication. Nothing in there reads the *contents* of the files.

Answer (score 1):

`$files` is not an array. It is a string.

You are splitting it on whitespace. This is not safe for filenames with spaces.

You are also globbing. This isn't safe for filenames with globbing metacharacters in the names.

See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for how to safely operate over data line-by-line. Also see [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

You can also get `find` to spit out arbitrarily formatted output with the `-printf` argument. (i.e. `-printf %f` will print out just the file name (no path information).)

You don't need `echo` for that variable assignment. (i.e. `formatted=${file##*/}` works just fine.)

`$formatted` contains a *single* filename. You can't really `sort` or `uniq` a single item.

Putting all the above together and assuming that you want to detect duplicates by suffix-less name (and not file contents) then...

If you aren't worried about filenames with newlines then you can just use this:

```
find /root/123 -type f \( -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.bat" \) -printf %f | sort | uniq -c
```

If you *are* worried about them then you need to read the lines manually (something like this for bash 4+):

```
declare -A files
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    ((files["$file"]+=1))
done <(find /root/123 -type f \( -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.bat" \) -printf '%f\0')
declare -p files
```

Comment: for clarity, that first example using `find` (assuming files without newlines in the filename, which surprisingly can happen more often than one would think & should be verified), there needs to be a newline in the printf, e.g., `find ... -printf '%f\n' | sort ...`, and also if it's desired to remove file extensions: `find ... -printf '%f\n' | sed 's/\....$//' | sort  | uniq -c` (note: the `sed` looks for a period ("`\.`") followed by _any_ three characters at the end of the line ("`...$`" ) and replaces them with nothing ("`//`") before sorting and reporting unique counts.

Comment: part #2, again regarding the first example using `find`: it is possible to use `find` with `nut` separated output (so it works with filenames with newlines), but this assumes GNU find, sort and uniq: `find {dir} -name (etc)  -type f -print0 | sort -z | uniq -c -z | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'` although this example doesn't strip the file extension OR the path, that is left as an exercise to the reader :-) (but it's not terribly difficult). The `find ... -print0` uses `null` terminated output, so you need a version of `sort` and `uniq` that accept this as input (see the `-z` option).